# How to exclude model's shadows on itself?

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I have a `SCNLight` with type `SCNLightTypeDirectional`. When scene rendered, model casts shadows on itself and It wasn't I expectation. How to exclude model's shadows on itself?

Or how to smooth the shadows edge? It looks very unnatural now.

There is the scenario :
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I find a simple way to achieve this but loss some material details.

Change the light model of  material to `SCNLightingModelConstant` and exclude model from lighting calculation of your `SCNLight`.

**1. set light model**

`SCNLightingModelConstant` only consider ambient light to shading, so We need ambient lights to keep model visible.

```
model.geometry.materials.firstObject.lightingModelName = SCNLightingModelConstant;
```

**2. set category bit mask of model and lights**

```
model.categoryBitMask = 1;
directionalLight.categoryBitMask = ~1UL;
```

If results of bitwise AND of `categoryBitMask` is zero, node will not take consideration into light illumination, so there no self-shadows anymore. Shadows model casted will still remain in scene.